# def multiply_matrix (non unmpy)

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
`def mat_Multiply(A,B):
        result = []
        for i in range(l en(A[0])):
            total = 0
            for j in range (l en(A)):
                total += A[i][] * B[i][j]
            result.append(total)
        return result
```

---

```
error code
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-155-e15a98952d0a> in <module>()
     36     mat_1 = makeMatrix(2,3)
     37     mat_2 = makeMatrix(3,2)
---> 38     result = matMul(mat_1,mat_2)
     39     print(mat_1)
     40     print(mat_2)

<ipython-input-155-e15a98952d0a> in matMul(mat1, mat2)
     15         total = 0
     16         for j in range(len(mat1)):
---> 17             total += mat1[i][j] * mat2[j][i]
     18         result.append(total)
     19     return result

IndexError: list index out of range
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do not use with numpy. 
def must be defined. I think this part is very difficult.
infinity error...
please help

Comment: Hi @User995152, what is the error you get? Could you please edit your question and add the traceback as well?

Comment: thaks bro I posted an error code. Can you take a look at the problem once?

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like your traceback is pointing to a different code, could you update your `mat_Multiply` function to reflect the one you're using?

Comment: Also can you add an example of what `mat1` and `mat2` are? So we could reproduce your error and give you some advice!

Answer (score 0):

```
def mat_Multiply(A, B):
  # Create the Results array with dimensions
  # number_of_rows(A) x number_of_columns(B)
  result = [[0 for col in range(len(B[0]))] for row in range(len(A))]
  # loop through rows of A
  for i in range(len(A)):
    # loop through cols of B
    for j in range(len(B[0])):
      # loop through rows of B
      for k in range(len(B)):
        #simple math
        result[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j]
  return result


A = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
B = [[7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]

print A
print B

print mat_Multiply(A, B)
```

Comment: Hi @mlwn, could you please add some explanation to your answer? Although code only answers are generally accepted, I think it's better to provide some context here, as your code is quite long.

Comment: I removed the tests for correct input as they are not required by the poster.. I just left the base code which is self explanatory

Comment: It is self-explanatory to people used to python, it might not be the same for newbies...

Comment: One minute... doing the comments